# How do I filter a list without using List.filter in OCaml?

Tags: list, ocaml

I have to write a function that, given two lists, it returns a list of the elements of the first one whose square is present in the second one (sry for my english). I can't do it recursively and i can't use List.filter.
this is what i did:

```
let lst1= [1;2;3;4;5];;
let lst2= [9;25;10;4];;

let filquadi lst1 lst2 =
  let aux = [] in 
  List.map(fun x -> if List.mem (x*x) lst2 then x::aux else []) lst1;;
```

It works but it also prints [] when the number doesn't satisfy the if statement:

```
filquadi lst1 lst2 ;;
- : int list list = [[]; [2]; [3]; []; [5]]
```

how can I return a list of numbers instead of a list of a list of numbers?

```
- : int list = [2;3;5]
```

Comment: Can't use `List.filter` and can't use recursion with _lists_? That seems very restrictive.

Comment: Indeed, can't do it `recursively` is to deliberately look away(abstracted) from something that happens eventually, if we continue to use functions from `List` module.  If not recursion, then we will have to use the limited form of `for` and `do` looping constructs supported by the language, but then the style becomes `imperative`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use List.concat to put things together at the end:

```
List.concat (List.map ...)
```

As a side comment, `aux` isn't doing anything useful in your code. It's just a name for the empty list (since OCaml variables are immutable). It would probably be clearer just to use `[x]` instead of `x :: aux`.

As another side comment, this is a strange sounding assignment. Normally the reason to forbid use of functions from the `List` module is to encourage you to write your own recursive solution (which indeed is educational). I can't see offhand a reason to forbid the use of recursion, but it's interesting to combine functions from `List` in different ways.

Comment: Could also use `List.filter_map` and have the function return an `option` instead, but these constraints seem very arbitrary.

Comment: ty very much. I found it weird too. I had to do this recursively, with list.filter and this way

Answer (score 3):

Your criteria don't say you can't use `List.fold_left` or `List.rev`, so...

```
let filter lst1 lst2 =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun init x -> 
       if List.mem (x * x) lst2 then x::init 
       else init) 
    [] lst1 
  |> List.rev
```

We start with an empty list, and as we fold over the first list, add the current element only if that element appears in the second list. Because this results in a list that's reversed from its original order, we then reverse that.

If you're not supposed to use recursion, this is technically cheating, because `List.fold_left` works recursively, but then so does basically anything working with lists. Reimplementing the `List` module's functions is going to involve a lot of recursion, as can be seen from reimplementing `fold_left` and `filter`.

```
let rec fold_left f init lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> init
  | x::xs -> fold_left f (f init x) xs

let rec filter f lst =
  match lst with 
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs when f x -> x :: filter f xs
  | _::xs -> filter f xs
```